# How can a large number of GitHub issues be reviewed and updated efficiently?

Tags: git, github

I would often need to review and update 100+ GitHub Issues. The current GitHub webui is difficult for this process. How can a large number of issues be reviewed and updated efficiently?

Comment: This is a social question. You may need more manpower

Comment: if it's automated changes, github has [an api](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/)

Comment: The API is a good suggestion.  I feel like there should be an app that uses it already, maybe some Electron app or something.  I've found this: https://www.neat.io/bee/    and this  https://gitscout.com  which are both native macOS apps, but they both are discontinued now.  Is there app out there that is currently supported?

Comment: If you're looking for a different interface for this kinda thing, you may want to check out the kanbanish support here: https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/about-project-boards

Comment: Justin - thanks for the pointer.  We've reviewed that and, while we do use Projects, it isn't a good way to triage and periodically review and update the issues. Our current workflow is, basically, once a month we review all the open issues to make sure we have the latest info added and identify actions to move things forward (assign, clarify, etc.)